# Armadillo randu doesn't work

Tags: c++, armadillo

I met a very strange problem. The random function of `armadillo` doesn't work. It only return zeros. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // 2D field of matrices; 3D fields are also supported
    field<mat> F(4, 2);

    for (uword col = 0; col < F.n_cols; ++col)
        for (uword row = 0; row < F.n_rows; ++row) {
            F(row, col) = randu < mat > (2, 3);  // each element in field<mat> is a matrix
        }

    F.print("F:");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

F:

```
[field column 0]
        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0


[field column 1]
        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0

        0        0        0
        0        0        0
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Tried your code and it worked fine (using Armadillo 6.700.4). Have you tried to make a clean build?

Comment: @ClaesRolen Thanks for your comment. Yeah this is so weird. What do you mean by "make a clean build"?

Comment: Remove all your generated .o files and compile once again to make sure  the build is based on your lastest source file version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (on Windows). I commented out the following line in config.hpp

```
#define ARMA_USE_WRAPPER
```

and after that the randu/randn etc. commands worked correctly.